# Executing command string built in shell script

Tags: json, shell, jq

I'm trying to build a command string in a for loop and execute it.
However that doesn't go as planned.
While in fact, running last 2 lines in comment do seem to work.
How do I get this solved?  How do you build a command string the right way?

Any help is much appreciated!

```
#!/bin/sh
JSONQUERYFILE="ReportingQueries.json"
JQCOMMAND="/C/gitBashCmd/jq-win64.exe"

for i in $($JQCOMMAND -c -r '.FilterQueries[].Id' $JSONQUERYFILE) 
    do
        #remove weird chars from $i...      
        forId=$(echo $i | tr -d '\r')
        jqFilterString=".FilterQueries[] | if .Id == \"$forId\" then \"YES\" else \"NOPE\" end"
        echo $jqFilterString 
        commandString="$JQCOMMAND -c -r '"$jqFilterString"' $JSONQUERYFILE"

        echo $commandString
        $($commandString)
#       echo /C/gitBashCmd/jq-win64.exe -c -r '.FilterQueries[] | if .Id == "274005" then "YES" else "NOPE" end' ReportingQueries.json
#       /C/gitBashCmd/jq-win64.exe -c -r '.FilterQueries[] | if .Id == "274005" then "YES" else "NOPE" end' ReportingQueries.json
done
```

The output of the 2 last lines in comment seems to work fine:  (the jq-win64 command iterates on itself)

```
.FilterQueries[] | if .Id == "274301" then "YES" else "NOPE" end
/C/gitBashCmd/jq-win64.exe -c -r .FilterQueries[] | if .Id == "274005" then "YES" else "NOPE" end ReportingQueries.json
NOPE
YES
NOPE
NOPE
.FilterQueries[] | if .Id == "274005" then "YES" else "NOPE" end
/C/gitBashCmd/jq-win64.exe -c -r .FilterQueries[] | if .Id == "274005" then "YES" else "NOPE" end ReportingQueries.json
NOPE
YES
NOPE
NOPE
.FilterQueries[] | if .Id == "274004" then "YES" else "NOPE" end
/C/gitBashCmd/jq-win64.exe -c -r .FilterQueries[] | if .Id == "274005" then "YES" else "NOPE" end ReportingQueries.json
NOPE
YES
NOPE
NOPE
.FilterQueries[] | if .Id == "274000" then "YES" else "NOPE" end
/C/gitBashCmd/jq-win64.exe -c -r .FilterQueries[] | if .Id == "274005" then "YES" else "NOPE" end ReportingQueries.json
NOPE
YES
NOPE
NOPE
```

While if we run the script with the built up command string the output is the following:

```
.FilterQueries[] | if .Id == "274301" then "YES" else "NOPE" end
/C/gitBashCmd/jq-win64.exe -c -r '.FilterQueries[] | if .Id == "274301" then "YES" else "NOPE" end' ReportingQueries.json
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end (Windows cmd shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
'.FilterQueries[]
jq: 1 compile error
.FilterQueries[] | if .Id == "274005" then "YES" else "NOPE" end
/C/gitBashCmd/jq-win64.exe -c -r '.FilterQueries[] | if .Id == "274005" then "YES" else "NOPE" end' ReportingQueries.json
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end (Windows cmd shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
'.FilterQueries[]
jq: 1 compile error
.FilterQueries[] | if .Id == "274004" then "YES" else "NOPE" end
/C/gitBashCmd/jq-win64.exe -c -r '.FilterQueries[] | if .Id == "274004" then "YES" else "NOPE" end' ReportingQueries.json
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end (Windows cmd shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
'.FilterQueries[]
jq: 1 compile error
.FilterQueries[] | if .Id == "274000" then "YES" else "NOPE" end
/C/gitBashCmd/jq-win64.exe -c -r '.FilterQueries[] | if .Id == "274000" then "YES" else "NOPE" end' ReportingQueries.json
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end (Windows cmd shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
'.FilterQueries[]
jq: 1 compile error
```

Comment: Are you trying to compare the same `.id` fields on the same file? Won't they all be `YES`? If you describe what you're trying to do, it can probably be done in a single `jq`. Note that you can insert a shell variable with `jq --arg name value`.

Comment: You shouldn't be generating code from the shell in the first place. `jq -r --arg id "$forId" '.FilterQueries[] | if .Id == $id then "YES" else "NOPE" end' ReportingQueries.json`

Comment: The correct way to "build" a command line is to use an array (for a single command + arguments), or to create a string and `eval` it (potential security problems if not used very carefully). But I don't see the need for either of those here.

Comment: What I'm trying to do, is to iterate over the elements in FilterQueries[], and fetch the data in it, to run a command with it.  The way I do that is to get the data for an with an inline if else whereas I compare the Id with the iterated value. 
Currently I show a *YES NOPE* to simplify my command that isn't working.
In reality I return an *empty* if I'm not finding it.

Answer (score 0):

@dan @ikegami Thank you SO much for the hint --arg.
This is the better version:

```
#!/bin/sh
JSONQUERYFILE="ReportingQueries.json"
JQCOMMAND="/C/gitBashCmd/jq-win64.exe"

for i in $($JQCOMMAND -c -r '.FilterQueries[].Id' $JSONQUERYFILE) 
    do  
        forId=$(echo $i | tr -d '\r')         #remove weird chars from $i...   
        echo $JQCOMMAND -c -r --arg idToSearch "$forId" '.FilterQueries[] | if .Id == $idToSearch then "YES" else "NOPE" end' $JSONQUERYFILE 
        $JQCOMMAND -c -r --arg idToSearch "$forId" '.FilterQueries[] | if .Id == $idToSearch then "YES" else "NOPE" end' $JSONQUERYFILE
done
```

And it produces the following output:

```
/C/gitBashCmd/jq-win64.exe -c -r --arg idToSearch 274301 .FilterQueries[] | if .Id == $idToSearch then "YES" else "NOPE" end ReportingQueries.json
YES
NOPE
NOPE
NOPE
/C/gitBashCmd/jq-win64.exe -c -r --arg idToSearch 274005 .FilterQueries[] | if .Id == $idToSearch then "YES" else "NOPE" end ReportingQueries.json
NOPE
YES
NOPE
NOPE
/C/gitBashCmd/jq-win64.exe -c -r --arg idToSearch 274004 .FilterQueries[] | if .Id == $idToSearch then "YES" else "NOPE" end ReportingQueries.json
NOPE
NOPE
YES
NOPE
/C/gitBashCmd/jq-win64.exe -c -r --arg idToSearch 274000 .FilterQueries[] | if .Id == $idToSearch then "YES" else "NOPE" end ReportingQueries.json
NOPE
NOPE
NOPE
YES
```